# csvlog of postgres 13 seems to be corrupted

Tags: postgresql

The csvlog of postgres 13 has an extra column (backend_type) which is not a problem.
But not all the lines have the correct layout.
In mij example the first line is correct, but the second line has several extra columns.
This of course is a problem when writing the file to a table via the copy command.
Is there anyone else with this problem?

Line 1:
2021-09-13 13:03:17.132 CEST,"postgres","ubenchdb",5361,"10.0.10.109:50726",613f2ff5.14f1,1,"idle",2021-09-13 13:03:17 CEST,3/0,0,LOG,08006,"could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer",,,,,,,,,"postgres_fdw","client backend"

Line 2:
2021-09-13 13:03:17.193 CEST,"postgres","ubenchdb",5362,"10.0.10.109:50728",613f2ff5.14f2,1,"idle",2021-09-13 13:03:17 CEST,3/0,0,LOG,08006,"could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer",,,,,,t: Connection reset by peer",,,,,,,,,"postgres_fdw","client backend"

This is my log related config:

```
log_destination = 'csvlog'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = '/media/nfs/ProdShare/postgres/logs/approvaldb'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H.log'
log_truncate_on_rotation = on
log_rotation_age = 1h
log_rotation_size = 0
log_min_duration_statement = 5000
log_lock_waits = on
log_temp_files = 0
log_autovacuum_min_duration = 10000
```

It looks like I can't attach the log file here, but I will paste 3 lines before the problem line, the problem line itself and 3 after the problem line so you have an idea:

2021-09-13 13:03:13.177 CEST,"postgres","ubenchdb",5357,"10.0.10.109:50722",613f2ff1.14ed,1,"idle",2021-09-13 13:03:13 CEST,3/0,0,LOG,08006,"could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer",,,,,,,,,"postgres_fdw","client backend"
2021-09-13 13:03:13.232 CEST,"postgres","ubenchdb",5358,"10.0.10.109:50724",613f2ff1.14ee,1,"idle",2021-09-13 13:03:13 CEST,3/0,0,LOG,08006,"could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer",,,,,,,,,"postgres_fdw","client backend"
2021-09-13 13:03:17.132 CEST,"postgres","ubenchdb",5361,"10.0.10.109:50726",613f2ff5.14f1,1,"idle",2021-09-13 13:03:17 CEST,3/0,0,LOG,08006,"could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer",,,,,,,,,"postgres_fdw","client backend"
2021-09-13 13:03:17.193 CEST,"postgres","ubenchdb",5362,"10.0.10.109:50728",613f2ff5.14f2,1,"idle",2021-09-13 13:03:17 CEST,3/0,0,LOG,08006,"could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer",,,,,,t: Connection reset by peer",,,,,,,,,"postgres_fdw","client backend"
2021-09-13 13:04:09.423 CEST,"postgres","ubenchdb",32291,"10.0.10.109:33276",613f3029.7e23,1,"idle",2021-09-13 13:04:09 CEST,79/0,0,LOG,08006,"could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer",,,,,,,,,"postgres_fdw","client backend"
2021-09-13 13:04:09.633 CEST,"postgres","ubenchdb",32292,"10.0.10.109:33278",613f3029.7e24,1,"idle",2021-09-13 13:04:09 CEST,79/0,0,LOG,08006,"could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer",,,,,,,,,"postgres_fdw","client backend"
2021-09-13 13:04:13.581 CEST,"postgres","ubenchdb",32299,"10.0.10.109:33280",613f302d.7e2b,1,"idle",2021-09-13 13:04:13 CEST,79/0,0,LOG,08006,"could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer",,,,,,,,,"postgres_fdw","client backend"

Comment: You have some mismatched quoting there somehow I think. Look around the `t: Connection reset by peer"` - there's no opening quote.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any control over this. These lines are being logged by postgres in the csvlog. It looks like postgres is merging 2 lines which makes the loffile corrupt.

Comment: I don't think so. Perhaps your editor has a problem.

Comment: No I've checked with nano and vim. I also copied the file from the server to my local machine and opened it with notepad++ and Ms Excel.  The content of the file is what I've posted in my question.

Comment: What is your configuration for the logging-related parameters?  How intensive was the logging activity during this time?  Can you share raw log file someplace that we can download it?  Like the others, I think this is much more likely to be a user error or a tooling error than true corruption.

Comment: I found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I copied the config files to the standby server so the standby server was logging to the same shared directory and file.  I changed the config and now the problem is solved.
Thanks and sorry everyone for your time!